# Is there a way to animate a texture based on camera position in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, geometry

i'm pretty new to Three.js
and i want to recreate this effect.
[Animatd texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6P3v.gif)

I want to also be able to add my own shaders to the cube and to use a video texture maybe slightly distorted.
I've been scouring the web for some sort of idea on how to get started, but i have reached no conclusion

I tried making use of the stencil buffer but to no avail, i wasn't able to then use any shader/material to recreate some sort of PBR glass effect

EDIT:

For those that are looking for the same thing, i found a library which does exactly that https://github.com/marcofugaro/three-projected-material